# Bean «templateEngine» never gets instantiated

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf with Spring.
There are three beans for it:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine engine) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver resolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return resolver;
}
```

Yesterday everything worked fine.
For now, the middle one, templateEngine, never gets called at all, so I get

```
2016-06-15 01:14:14.853  WARN 9014 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.t.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration     : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

and

```
Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Why does it occur?

Comment: Okaaay, as a workaround I've written this, see last code block: http://aquadc.net/blog/articles/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_Thymeleaf_%D0%B2_Spring